# modify volume on windows only for one application

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows

I have this code on windows 7 for volume managment. With this, i modify the volume for the whole operating system.
But in windows 7 and news operating systems, if we click on the volume icon and open the volumen manager, we can see icons with the apps using the sound system on the Pc. and here, we can modify the volume only for one program, not for the whole OS.

Im looking for modify from VB.net the volume for only one program.
Thanks in advance.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function
    Const WM_APPCOMMAND As UInteger = &H319
    Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP As UInteger = &HA
    Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN As UInteger = &H9
    Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE As UInteger = &H8
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For i = 0 To 5
            SendMessage(Me.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, &H30292, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP * &H10000)
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        For i = 0 To 5
            SendMessage(Me.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, &H30292, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN * &H10000)
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        SendMessage(Me.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, &H200EB0, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE * &H1000
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If you adjust the output device volume it adjusts the software volumes accordingly. Can you show a screenshot of yours being different?

Comment: You can see here: [link]http://imgur.com/a/Yzdm7

Comment: Yes, so if you can change the leftmost slider, all the others will change with it.

Comment: Yes, that is. What i need is to move anyone one by one as i explain on the question

Comment: Ahh, the question isn't overly clear. Did you actually try and modify your program in any way to achieve what you need?

Comment: If i put the question, is because i don't know how to do that.

Comment: The solutions viewed following the link for the already answered question doesn't work for me :-( any help, please?